# QML retrieve checkbox status in tableview

Tags: qt, qml

I have a window which contains a tableview with 2 columns: one containing checkboxes and one containing strings. 
The model for the tableview is a listmodel which has only a field (the value of item). 
My question is, how can i get the status of the checkboxes for each string in the tableview? If I do a getrow on the model, I will receive only the value of the string but not the status of the checkbox (because is not part of the model). 
Thanks

Comment: The easiest would be, to make it part of the model.

Comment: I made it part of the model and it is ok now but i got into another problem.Based on the column the values of the model are strings or numbers(not in the same time). how can i select which value of the model to display ? like value: model.number or value: model.string

Comment: Read about [`TableViewColumn.role`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableviewcolumn.html#role-prop) and [`TableViewColumn.delegate`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableviewcolumn.html#delegate-prop)